# Strong Naming an assembly using command line compile

Tags: .net, vb.net, strongname, vbc, vb.net-2010

I am trying to use NAnt in order to compile and sign an assembly using the vbc compiler.  I have a project set up and am able to successfully sign the assembly compiling with VS2010.  When I try to sign it using the command line I get this error:

```
vbc : error BC30140: Error creating assembly manifest: Error signing assembly -- The parameter is incorrect.
```

I even created a trivially simple app (just an assemblyinfo.vb file) that will not compile and sign using vbc.exe  What am I doing wrong?

here is my assemblyinfo.vb:

```
Option Strict Off
Option Explicit On

Imports System
Imports System.Reflection
<Assembly: AssemblyVersionAttribute("2010.05.18.0918"),  _
 Assembly: AssemblyCopyrightAttribute("Copyright © Patient First 2007"),  _
 Assembly: AssemblyCompanyAttribute("Patient First, Inc."),  _
 Assembly: AssemblyProductAttribute("Patient First Framework"),  _
 Assembly: AssemblyDelaySign(false),  _
 Assembly: AssemblyKeyFile("test.pfx"), _
 Assembly: AssemblyTitleAttribute("PatientFirst.Framework")>
```

test.pfx is located in the same folder as assemblyinfo.vb

Here is how I am trying to compile it:

```
vbc /target:library /verbose assemblyinfo.vb
```

I also tried using

```
vbc /target:library /verbose assemblyinfo.vb /keyfile:test.pfx
```

and tried using /keyfile parameter without the AssemblyDelaySign and AssemblyKeyFile attributes

If I remove the AssemblyDelaySign and AssemblyKeyFile attributes and leave off the /keyfile command line parameter it compiles fine.  What is the correct way to do this with vbc?

--EDIT:
I have found that MSBuild also does not like having the AssemblyKeyFile attribute as I have defined it in the AssemblyInfo.vb, it gives the same failure message.  So the only way I can currently get this to build correctly is to set properties on the project to tell it which key file to use and to sign the assembly.

--EDIT:
The reason this appears to work building the project from within VS2010 is that msbuild is passing /keycontainer to vbc.exe on the command line instead of using /keyfile.  Still don't know how to use the /keyfile command line parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that MSBuild also does not like having the AssemblyKeyFile attribute as I have defined it in the AssemblyInfo.vb, it gives the same failure message. So the only way I can currently get this to build correctly is to set properties on the project to tell it which key file to use and to sign the assembly.

The reason this *appears* to work building the project from within VS2010 is that msbuild is passing /keycontainer to vbc.exe on the command line instead of using /keyfile. Still don't know how to use the /keyfile command line parameter.